# How to use Excel Power Query to access a postgresql database

Tags: excel, postgresql

We have a postgresql 9.0 database which we want to connect to via Excel 2010 running the Power Query plugin. I've setup the machine running excel to be able to use Npgsql to do the connection according to these instructions http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-a-postgresql-database-HA104028095.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA104003952. The connection fails in Excel with this error message:

> DataSource.Error: PostgreSQL: ERROR: 42883: function
>   concat(information_schema.character_data, unknown) does not exist
>   Details: Message=ERROR: 42883:..., ErrorCode=-2147467259

Has anyone successfully connected to a postgresql database from Excel using the Power Query plugin? There's a menu item on the power query ribbon in excel specifically for postgresql so I figured it would work. The concat function isn't in our postgresql version of 9.0 so do I have to upgrade our postgresql database to do this?

Comment: It seems you need to upgrade - `concat()` appeared in 9.1

Comment: Yeah I guess. I'm looking into pg_upgrade. I wonder why excel wants to use that function to simply connect to the database.

Comment: As "information_schema" is mentioned in the error, it probably retrieves some metadata (e.g. list of various existing DB objects).

Comment: A workaround is possible - see [here](https://drupal.org/node/555580).

Comment: Added the function Milen and then I could connect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can either upgrade or define your own function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE concat(information_schema.character_data, varchar) 
RETURNS varchar LANGUAGE SQL AS
$$ SELECT $1::varchar || $2; $$;
```

But upgrading to 9.1 seems likely the best approach.